# Save the contents of a text box in an array

Tags: c#

How can you save the contents of a text box in an array in C#?

```
string[] myArray = new string[1]; 
myArray[0] = textBox1.Text;
```

I want to save the details in a JSON file..

Comment: If you [edit] the question to add an example of what the JSON should look like, we may be able to help.

Comment: Why do you need an array when `myArray` contains only 1 `string`. Why not simply `string txt = textBox1.Text;` ?

Comment: If the content of the text box is already in the desired json format, you simply need to save it to a file (something like `File.WriteAllText(<filename>,  textBox1.Text);`).

Comment: Can you clarify the format of the string in the TextBox ? Is it already in json format ?

Comment: Or in one line `string[] myArray = new string[] { textBox1.Text };`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I get that correctly, but if you want to store an array (or any other object) as a JSON file, first convert it to JSON string.

The most popular and useful library is `Newtonsoft.Json` (the new name is `JSON.Net`).

To serialise an object to a string use the following code invocation:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
File.WriteAllText("path to the file", json);
```

Hope this sheds some light on your problem.

Comment: OP seems to already have a json string (although the question is not entirely clear). So why is there a need for `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` ?